# how to get document id index on firestore with flutter onTap method

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, indexing, categories

I am trying to get the document ID. I don't know if it is the right way, but until now I could manage to get all the IDs.

Then I am trying to get the document ID index so I can open the category with `onTap` and show the category products.

I have tried with map, forEach, etc... but nothing.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: StreamBuilder(
    stream: firestore.snapshots(),
    builder:(context, snapshot){
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
       return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());{
        final document = snapshot.data?.docs;

        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: document?.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap: (){
                    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('prova').get()
                        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
                      querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) {
                        print(doc.id);
                        var docId = doc.id;
                        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>
                            CategoriesPage(document: document[index]['name'], docId: docId)));
                      });
                    });
```

Comment: can you clarify what you expecting exactly to be done

Comment: I am trying to click on the category and open a page that shows all the products.
My problem is, to get the category index, so I can show the products for ecah category

Comment: Have you made a collection for each category? That would make it easier I believe

Comment: Categories, are created by users, so, basically, i don't know the category's ID. That's why i am trying to get the ID, and then pass it to the product page, to show products related to that category

Comment: No, every user has 1 collection with multiple categories, and each category has products inside. creating a collection for each category, i think i will be hard to manage, right?

Comment: You can only alternate collections and docs in Firebase. There is a way to do it, but the way you are descibing it here makes it seems like you are trying to put collections into collections. I'll make a detailed post below

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, the way FireStore allows you to store data is alternating between collections and docs. That's to say you can't put another doc into a doc, and another collection within a collection. You can only put docs in a collection, and then subcollections within a doc, etc, etc.

I'm unaware of your data structuring needs, however I'd suggest something like this:
[image]

When a user creates a category, simply add it to their doc, and then any products within the category could be placed into a sub-collection under that category. Let me know if that could work for you.